# Movie or series about a group of people who discover a portal to live forever

Tags: story-identification, movie

Movie or series about a group of people who discover a portal to live forever. There are even famous people. The portal opens every few years.
The portal is a child. People enter his mind and live all together.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds almost the same as "Being John Malkovich (1999)" except the portal is into John Malkovich's head not a childs. There's a lot of toing and froing within the story but ultimately the portal exists purely for a group of old people to live communally in a new body (ie. John Malkovich)

Comment: It looks like when you registered you account a second one was created instead of using the first. Please see the help page on [how to merge accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can take back ownership of this answer again.